# Velocity print values and their keys

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, key, velocity

I know this is a really beginner's question, but I have no choice :-) I need to write a program in Velocity which will take a Map and write all values and their keys (not keys and their values !!!) - every value is allowed to be recorded under more keys.

If you are able to do that, please help me, I will appreciate every answer :-)
Thank you very much!

In java it looks like this:

```
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("key1", "val1");
    map.put("key2", "val1");
    map.put("key3", "val2");
    map.put("key4", "val1");

    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> hmap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

    for (Entry<String, String> item : map.entrySet()) {
        String val = item.getValue();
        if (!hmap.containsKey(val)) {
            hmap.put(val, new ArrayList<String>());
            hmap.get(val).add(item.getKey());
        } else {
            hmap.get(val).add(item.getKey());
        }
    }

    for (Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> item : hmap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(item.getKey() + " " + item.getValue());
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I've solved it. Here is my solution:

```
#set($valToKey = {})
$!valToKey.put("aaa", ["bbb", "ccc"])
$!valToKey.get("aaa").add("ddd")

## fill valToKey map
#foreach($item in $tmp.entrySet())
    #foreach($value in $item.value)
        #if($valToKey.containsKey($value))
            $!valToKey.get($value).add($item.key) ## use of dummy to prevent printing 'true'
        #else
            $!valToKey.put($value, [$item.key])
        #end
    #end
#end

## print valToKey map
#foreach($item in $valToKey.entrySet())

    $item.key
    ## print all values according to key
    #foreach($value in $item.value)
        $indent  -> $value
    #end
#end
```

Comment: What dummy you used to prevent true from printing?

Comment: @user2900150 I'm sorry, the comment was supposed to be deleted :-)